# $CP^1$ as a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, complex-geometry

I do not know whether my logic is correct. I just want to have some confirmation as I do not want to talk nonsense.

I think $CP^1$ can be embedded into $CP^2$ as a curve. Let $[x,y,z]\in CP^2$. Choose $z=1$. Then we have $[\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z},1]$. Now choose $y$ fixed, we have a copy of $CP^1$. Now to see $CP^1$ as an algebraic curve in $CP^2$, it suffices to get a homogeneous degree $d$ polynomial. So we just choose $y=0$ as the above. So $CP^1=V(y,z-1)$. Is my reasoning correct? I think $CP^1$ is just a curve parametrized by $\frac{x}{z}$ but it is not clear to me this variety is a curve.

Comment: This is almost right, except you shouldn't "choose $z=1$." Just take $V(y)$.

Comment: @Nefertiti. Can you elaborate it a bit more? I have very basic notion of varieties but have no idea about projective varieties. Why I cannot choose $z=1$ or fix at a non-zero value? Should not the projective variety of $CP^1$ living in $C[x,y,z]$? Thanks.

Comment: If you set $z=1$ and $y=0$ you get points of the form $[x,0,1]$ with $x \in \mathbf C$ anything you like. But this is not $\mathbf {CP}^1$; it is just $\mathbf C$.

Comment: @Nefertiti. Ah, yes. I am being stupid. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, you can also embed $\Bbb CP^1$ into $\Bbb CP^2$ as a conic, e.g., $[s,t]\mapsto [s^2,st,t^2]$ (the compactification of $y=x^2$).